# Debugging Typescript Node app with attach

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm building a full stack boilerplate project with the following folder structure:

```
boilerplate-app
 |---server
   |---src
   |---dist
   |---node_modules
 |---client
 |---.vscode
   |---launch.json
```

The server is a node project which I would like to be able to debug using vscode's 'attach' mode as I already have various build scripts in use. One of these will build the source found in `src` and put it in `dist`.

The issue I am facing is that although I can attach a debugger, I cannot attach breakpoints to my `src` files - they are all labelled as 'unbound'. I can however breakpoint on the `list` files, however this is not ideal as the are deleted and rebuilt when I change a `src` file.

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Server attach",
            "type": "node",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "restart": true,
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/server/src",
            "remoteRoot": "/Users/username/Documents/Development/express-app-boilerplate/server/src",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/server/dist/**/*.js"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/server/src"
        }
    ]
}
```

some things I'm not sure on:

- `${workspaceFolder}` in this instance I think refers to the `boilerplate-app` folder as that's the root folder I have open
- I am not clear on the meaning of `localRoot`/`remoteRoot` and `cwd`, or the difference between them - docs are minimal and seem to rely on the single-sentence summaries shown by intellisense.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2020"],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es2020",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "mapRoot": "dist"
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I'm fairly sure this is correct.

What do I need to do to get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to delete this but I resolved the issue:

launch.json changes:

removed `src` from

- `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/server"`
- `"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/server"`
- `"remoteRoot": "/Users/username/Documents/Development/express-app-boilerplate/server"`

tsconfig.js changes:

- removed `mapRoot`

Answer (score 0):

late response but you could also do this this way for a cleaner absolute path:

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Debug Server",
          "type": "node",
          "request": "attach",
          "port": 9030,
          "restart": true,
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/server",
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/server"
      }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure how you ran the code but I compile it before with nodemon.
This is my `nodemon.json`:

```
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": ".ts",
    "ignore": [],
    "exec": "npm run build && npm run start:dev"
}
```

and this is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "mywebsite",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rimraf dist/ && tsc",
        "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js",
        "start:dev": "node --inspect=9030 dist/index.js",
        "dev": "nodemon"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
        "@types/express-validator": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/morgan": "^1.9.9",
        "@types/node": "^20.9.4",
        "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
        "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "5.2.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0"
    }
}
```